# Regex substitution doesnt work in perl

Tags: perl

Below is self explanatory:

admin > cat test.pl

```
#!/bin/perl

$var1 = "SELECT * FROM CALENDAR WHERE CALNAME = ( SELECT * from EMP ) )";
$var2 = "( SELECT * from EMP )";
$var3 = "zyx";

if ($var1 =~ /EMP/)
{
    $var1 =~ s/$var2/$var3/;
}

print "var1=$var1\n";
```

admin > ./test.pl

```
var1=SELECT * FROM CALENDAR WHERE CALNAME = ( SELECT * from EMP ) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have special chars in `$var2` which should be [**quoted**](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) when used as literal chars,

```
$var1 =~ s/\Q$var2\E/$var3/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Comapre:

**Original:**

```
$var1 = "( SELECT * from EMP )";
$var2 = "abcd";

$var3 =~ s/$var1/$var2/;

print "var1=$var1\n";
print "var2=$var2\n";
print "var3=$var3\n";
```

**Working:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $var1 = "( SELECT * from EMP )";
my $var2 = "abcd";
my $var3 = "Something to keep, something to be replaced: ( SELECT * from EMP )";
$var3 =~ s/\Q$var1\E/$var2/;

print "var1=$var1\n";
print "var2=$var2\n";
print "var3=$var3\n";
```

Output:

```
var1=( SELECT * from EMP )
var2=abcd
var3=Something to keep, something to be replaced: abcd
```

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion worked. Wondoering what \Q and \E mean?

Comment: All chars between \Q\E are literal, you don't have to escape them.